# How can I bind C-M-g to wg-prefix-key?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm able to bind C-c w to wg-prefix-key

```
(setq wg-prefix-key (kbd "C-c w"))
```

, but not C-M-g

```
(setq wg-prefix-key (kbd "C-M-g"))
```

It says:

```
[134217735]
```

, in the Echo Area when I evaluate it.

If I hit C-M-g after I've tried to set it, it says:

```
C-M-g is undefined
```

, in the Echo Area

(describe-variable) says:

```
wg-prefix-key is a variable defined in ‘workgroups.el’.

Its value is [134217735]
Original value was ""
```

EDIT: Now even C-c w doesn't work. I'm not really sure what is happening here;). Never seen this before. Here's my config

```
#+begin_src elisp
(use-package workgroups2 :ensure t)
(require 'workgroups2)
(setq wg-prefix-key (kbd "C-M-g"))

(workgroups-mode 1)
#+end_src
```

Comment: You are almost certainly misinterpreting something. Evaluate the two `kbd` expressions in the `*scratch*` buffer and then the two `setq` expressions and get the value of `wg-prefix-key`  after each one: you should get `"^Cw" in the first case and `[134217735]` in the second (yes, both of those represent key sequences). So you have to say (a lot) more about why you think it's not working.

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. You don't say what the problem is you see with `C-M-g`. Also: only one question per post, please (I removed the question about registering a prefix key - please post that separately).